# Issue with GET, POST, PUT, DELETE requests in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've been encountering a strange issue where all of my links, even if I specify the request type, still sends GET requests. For example:

```
<%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i>".html_safe, workout_path(workout), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this workout?' }, :class => "delete-workout" %>
```

Will send a GET request and direct me to the workout show page, rather than delete it.

```
<%= link_to "Like", '/wellness/4/like',  method: :post, remote: true  %>
```

Does the same thing, sends a GET request, takes me to a show page with ID of 4, and I get the message:

> No route matches [GET] "/wellness/3/like"

which is correct since my route is:

```
post "/wellness/:id/like" => "wellness#like"
```

I do have jQuery ujs loading correctly so that isn't the issue as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Javascript is disabled in your browser. The [Rails documentation for link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) says:

> Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET.

One way to verify is to change your `link_to` to `button_to`, which is a safer choice, as explained in the [Rails documentation for button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to):

> Generates a form containing a single button that submits to the URL created by the set of options. This is the safest method to ensure links that cause changes to your data are not triggered by search bots or accelerators.

In general, it's best not to rely on JavaScript for major functionality because it's not guaranteed that your users will have it turned on. Implementing a major feature like deleting and liking that only works if JS is turned on is not considered a best practice. Instead, choose [progressive enhancement or graceful degradation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Graceful_degradation_versus_progressive_enhancement).

Comment: Yes thank you! So button_to does work but I'm curious as to why link_to doesn't work - I don't have JS disabled. In any case I'll be changing my link_to to button_to's.

Answer (score 0):

I think that error because resourses.

- Maybe you need.

> ```
> resourses wellness do
>   resourses likes
> end
> ```
>
> - Then run # rake routes you can see uri:
>
> `GET method   /wellness/:id/likes`

- Hope this helps!

Comment: That's not it, I checked routes, the route I need exists already